# Add a references to another document when using inserMany() using Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After I save a parent document, on the callback I save an array of child documents using Mongoose insertMany() but I want to save a reference of each of the child document's _id to the parent array.

When I console log the saved object it has a reference to  insertedIds: {...}.
What is the best way to save the id to parent.